# Save picture with mjpg-streamer on arduino Yun

Tags: image, save

I'm using mjpg-streamer to stream video to a webpage through the yun. The stream is working fine but since it's not recording and only live streaming I thought of having it capturing pictures from time to time (3 mins gap maybe) and add a button to the webpage to capture the picture as that button is pressed.
I decided to aproach the button first and the problem I found was that if the device is live streaming it can't take pictures at the same time, I have to stop the stream in order to capture the picture. I found that I can take a single picture when manualy typing the following commands:

```
/etc/init.d/mjpg-streamer stop 
mjpg_streamer -i "./input_uvc.so -d /dev/video0 -r 640x480 -yuv -n -f 1 -q 80" -o "./output_file.so -f ./tests/ -d 5000"
/etc/init.d/mjpg-streamer stop
/etc/init.d/mjpg-streamer start
```

but when having a .cgi file running all this the stream stops and the device keeps capturing pictures until rebooted...
I'm not fully aware of what all the parameters do here... Without a delay (-d) does the yun only take one picture or is it really necessary to have a certain delay value even if I only want one picture?
Is there a better way to achieve my goal?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Installing fswebcam and using:

```
#!/bin/ash
echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo
echo "<html><head><meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;URL=http://arduino/stream-url' /><title>Take Picture</title></head><body></body></html>"
/etc/init.d/mjpg-streamer stop
sleep 0.4; fswebcam /mnt/sda1/pictures/$(date +"%Y.%m.%d.%H.%M.%S").png
/etc/init.d/mjpg-streamer start
exit 0
```

was the best way around :)